# user defined psuedocolumn oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a large dataset in an oracle database that is currently accessed from Java one item at a time.  For example if a user is trying to do a bulk get of 50 items it will process them sequentially, calling a stored procedure for each one.  I am now trying to implement a bulk get, but am having some difficulty due to the way the user can pass in a range query:

An example table:

```
prim_key  |  identifier  |  start  |  end
----------+--------------+---------+-------
1         |  aaa         |  1      |  3
2         |  aaa         |  3      |  7
3         |  bbb         |  1      |  5
```

The way it works is that if you have a query like `(id='aaa' and pos=1)` it will find `prim_key = 1`, but if you query `(id='aaa' and pos=2)` it won't find anything.  If you do `(id='aaa' and pos=-2)` then it will again find prim_key=1 because the stored proc converts the -2 into a range scan equivalent to `start<=2` and `end>2`.

(Extra context: the start/end are actually dates and this querying mechanism allows efficient "latest as of date" queries as opposed to doing something like select prim_key,

```
start from myTable 
where start = (select max(start) from myTable where start <= 2))
```

This is all fine and works correctly for single gets, but now I'm trying to do bulk gets so that we can speed up the batch considerably.  The first attempt was to multithread the individual calls, but it put too much stress on the database to be doing so many parallel queries on the same table.  To solve this I've been trying to create a query like

```
select prim_key 
from myTable 
where (identifier='aaa' and start=3) 
or (identifier='aaa' and start<=2 and end>2)
```

building this up from the list of input parameters `('aaa',3 ; 'bbb',-2)`, which works well and produces an explain plan using all of the indexes I would expect.

**My Problem:** I need to know what the input parameters were that retrieved that row in order to do further processing and return the relevant prim_key.  I need to use something like a psuedocolumn that I can define myself:

```
select prim_key, PSUEDO 
from myTable 
where (identifier='aaa' and start=3 and PSUEDO='a3') 
or (identifier='aaa' and start<=2 and end>2 and PSUEDO='a-2')
```

but I can't find any way to return a value from the where clause, and I think subqueries would lose the indexing efficiencies gained by doing it all in one select.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
select
 prim_key,
 case when start = 3 then 'a3' else 'a-2' end pseudo
from
 you_table
where
 ...
```